# notepad++ - replace word with duplicate

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, notepad++

How do I replace

```
the, cat, walked, down, the, road
```

with

```
the [the], cat [cat], walked [walked], down [down], the [the], road [road]
```

? So far I've tried find:  (.+), replace: \1 [\1]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what is wrong with this question so I can make the adjustments?

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried so far? Let us not duplicate your efforts. Also, would you mind clarifying what exactly should/shouldn't be matched? Is it words? Any text before a comma? What exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match one or more  [word characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

```
\w+
```

and replace with `$0 [$0]`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eQ1kO0/1). `$0` is a full match of your regex.

---

Your regex `(.+),` would [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) [match](https://regex101.com/r/jL1yV6/1) until last occurrence of a comma.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.